# Is there any limit on the number of WPF DispatchTimers that can be used

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF project where I have many small control "widgets" I display (these can add up to over a few thousand in some instances).

I now wish to add a small ongoing animation to scroll through one of the text fields to swap between various different values. So I need to add some sort of timer to trigger the animation (or change the value, which would then trigger an animation)

Since there are so many instances, I am not sure whether to do the neater and simpler way I adding a [DispatchTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer?view=netframework-4.7.2) to the control class (so there is an instance of DispatchTimer for each instance of the control), or, if there is some performance overhead of doing this, have some static, or injected single instance of the DispatchTimer that would then just call a method on each control.

I am always careful here, as in the Winform days, there were always limits on Handles, User objects etc.

Looking at the [Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#windowsbase/Base/System/Windows/Threading/Dispatcher.cs,c12c04e2370d6739), I do see a `HandleRef` being created at line 2982:

```
  SafeNativeMethods.SetTimer(
                    new HandleRef(this, _window.Value.Handle),
                    TIMERID_TIMERS,
                    delta);
```

However, [HandlRef](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/DotNET/DotNET/8@0/untmp/whidbey/REDBITS/ndp/clr/src/BCL/System/Runtime/InteropServices/HandleRef@cs/1/HandleRef@cs) seems to be nothing more than a simple wrapper.

I haven't examined all the source code, was wondering if anyone had any prior knowledge about this?

Comment: Are you sure, that you need a timer for this? Why not to use WPF animation Storyboards?

Comment: So what I will have is, for example, a single `TextBock` which has a `list of values` I wish to scroll through. So I need something (a timer) to periodically get the next item in the list and then set the actual single value that the TextBlock is bound to. I will then use the `animation StoryBook` to do the actual animation (eg change opacity, or scroll haven't made up my mind yet). But as I can see, I still need the timer to actually trigger all of this?

Comment: I see now. Then, how about have a single `DispatchTimer` in some shared service (like `ITimerService`) which just raises an event (like `ITimerService.Elapsed`). Then you can inject this service in your ViewModels, which will change their `CurrentValue` when this event will raise? As far as I know, binded value chage can trigger an animation.

Comment: Yeah, probably agree with that, ie single injected instance, even if there is no limit (I am guessing there is no limit, but would still be interested in knowing, for any future reference)